# Where does EJB client resides and EJB Container resides in application server

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, application-server

I am new to EJB and wants to clear some doubts.

In application server we have **EJB Container** + **(servlets and JSPs)** + others.

EJB Container has EJB Components and which in turn has EJB's.

My question is where exactly EJB clients resides? 
Is it resides in same application server and/or in other application server? and what is @Local and @Remote in EJB.

Answer (score 0):

The client(s) of your EJB service might be nearly everywhere. Clients could be other EJB services or CDI Beans in the same application, or in other applications on the same application server, or even some plain Java SE application on a different machine and/or JVM.
The client is simply the "module" which uses the EJB service.

With @Local / @Remote you do specify the business interface of your session bean. In particular you have to specifiy a business interface with @Remote if you want to use the EJB service from an external client like the standalone Java SE application on a different JVM.

Comment: Is different JVM means different application server? and what do you mean by other applications on same application server. Can you please tell me which other applications are present for an example.

Comment: Do you know what the JVM is? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) .. and a Java Application Server is able to host multiple applications. You are able to user EJB services from one application in the other applications which are hosted on your application server.

Answer (score 0):

If you start a server instance the complete server will run in the same JVM but might contain several different applications.
So different server or different JVM mean the same.

A bit complicated is if you look to WildFly domain mode. Here you start one instance, but this instance is the contoller and might start 1...n instances of servers.

In any case if you use @Local interfaces the client and server must be deployed in the same Instance (but can be different applications).

If you use @Remote it can be the same or a different Instance and it depends on the configuration whether you have "call by value" or "call by reference" for the parameters.
The container or your application must have been configured for the invocation, i.e. by specify the foreign host and port for the connection.